# I want jQuery to stop snapping my loading div content into a weird position

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a quick jQuery question (well I'm hoping it's quick anyway!) I've been combing the forums and can't stop the code from snapping to a weird scroll position (I don't want it to scroll at all, just stay in the same place). I have a feeling this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out! Could you help me out? If it takes too long or you don't want to do it, I understand! All the jQuery, CSS and HTML code is live on Tumblr:

http://patriciahighsmith.tumblr.com/quiz

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.msg_body:not(:first)').hide();
    $("a.linkclass").click(function()
    {
        $('.msg_body').fadeOut("slow");
        $($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the default event from happening (which is following the anchor). You can either do this by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or returning false from the event handler (the latter [will also stop propagation](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), so use with care).

```
$("a.linkclass").click(function(event) {
    $('.msg_body').fadeOut("slow");
    $($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$("a.linkclass").click(function() {
    $('.msg_body').fadeOut("slow");
    $($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but now the "good choice" line of code is snapping in a strange way. Is there anyway to tell it not to snap? I really just want one response to fade in or out when clicked. Thank you so much!!! :) patriciahighsmith.tumblr.com/quiz

Answer (score 0):

Add [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to your click handler:

```
$("a.linkclass").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.msg_body').fadeOut("slow");
    $($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");
});​
```

The problem comes when you click on your anchor with `linkclass` class name, your browser starts navigating to the URL which it set in `href` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but now the "good choice" line of code is snapping in a strange way. Is there anyway to tell it not to snap? I really just want one response to fade in or out when clicked. Thank you so much!!! :) http://patriciahighsmith.tumblr.com/quiz