# How can I disable a strange JQuery snapping effect when new content is loaded into a div tag?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the "good choice" line of code not to snap up, but to appear in the same place as the previous question about Europe? Is there anyway to tell it not to snap?

I really just want one response to fade in or out when clicked but in the same position. Thank you! All the code below is live and on **Tumblr** (HTML, CSS and JQuery).

[patriciahighsmith.tumblr.com/quiz](http://patriciahighsmith.tumblr.com/quiz)

Comment: Reference to first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740846/i-want-jquery-to-stop-snapping-my-loading-div-content-into-a-weird-position

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just fading out you could try a fadeOut and slideUp at the same time, so the content doesn't just disappear, it slides up.  Or you could only display the next part once the first one fades out and is already hidden.

To do what you want you need to have:

```
var me = $(this);
$('.msg_body').fadeOut("slow", function()
{
    $(me.attr("href")).fadeIn("slow");
});
```